# How to prevent Google Chrome from shrinking favicons on memory saver tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

When Chrome [offloads a tab from memory](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12929150?hl=en) and makes it inactive, it now shrinks the tab's favicon to surround it with a circle. The problem is that it makes the offloaded tabs essentially unusable, there just isn't enough pixels for what Chrome wants to do there.

[image: Chrome inactive tabs]

I have a 4k display and from where I normally sit it's gone from "I know which tabs are which pages" to "red favicon", "black favicon", "looks like Drive", "black favicon", "no idea what's that", etc.

Is there any way to keep using Chrome's memory saver feature but make it not change favicons?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had a look through the chrome flags, and found this:

chrome://flags/#memory-saver-discarded-tab-treatment

[image]

I'm testing it out right now, but it seems like it's the one as it has options of "ring" opacity.

Comment: This workaround is now gone: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40278320