# Chrome - don't show dashed border around inactive tabs

Tags: google-chrome, mac

Chrome has started suspending inactive tabs (the option is called Memory Saver), which is fine, but it puts a dashed border around the favicons which makes it hard (for me) to see what they are.

I'm using Version 116.0.5845.187 (Official Build) (arm64) on MacOS.

Is there a setting anywhere to not show this border, without turning Memory Saver off completely?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Google Chrome from shrinking favicons on memory saver tabs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1807949/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-from-shrinking-favicons-on-memory-saver-tabs)

Comment: Yes it does - thanks! I will mark this question as a duplicate of that other one.